# Cisco reputation filters mis-identified site as malware or "misconfigured DNS"

Tags: domain-name-system, security, cisco, malware, webfilter

A client came back to me this morning saying one of their clients couldn't access the website because their security service was identifying it as a threat. I searched for the particular error, but every result on all 4 pages of Google results were forum users being unable to access that particular forum from work. The error is:

```
Based on your corporate access policies, this web site has been blocked because it 
has been determined by Web Reputation Filters to be a security threat to your 
computer or the corporate network. This web site has been associated with 
malware/spyware.

Threat Type: Othermalware 
Threat Reason: IP address is either verified as a bot or has misconfigured DNS.

Notification codes: 
(1, MALWARE, Othermalware, IP address is either verified as a bot or has 
misconfigured DNS., BLOCK-MALWARE, 0x03709539, 1311266207.636, 
AAAAGQAAAAAAAAAAJf8ACP8AAAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=)
```

This doesn't seem very common but I've been unable to find anyone clear this up from the server side. Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Is it flagging the corporate website, or some random website?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, verified as a bot **OR** has misconfigured DNS.  That's not a wide set of criteria at *all*.  If what you've got in this question is the only info you have to go on, I think you're screwed.  Some things that would help you towards a solution, though, include:

- Find out what bovine excrement is causing the problem.  If you've got a product, you can perhaps get onto their help system and get more details on their criteria.
- Contact the person who is getting blocked and get *them* to chase the provider of the aforesaid excrement regarding the issue.  That rather depends on their level of need for visiting your website; if it's not a corporate requirement, you'll probably be SOL here.
- Use some DNS checkers, such as http://dnsstuff.com/, to try and identify and fix any legitimate issues that might be present.  I'd recommend that become a part of your regular admin practices, by the way -- don't wait until the next issue to check your zone again.

Comment: The so-called "bovine excrement" [is Cisco](http://ironport.com./pdf/ironport_wbrs_datasheet.pdf).

Comment: That lines up with my experiences of them.